# Convert wchar_t to char with boost locale

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, boost, clang

My goal is to convert `wchar_t` to `char`,  my approach was to use `boost::locale` (using boost 1.60). For example,

`wchar_t * myWcharString = "0000000002" (Memory 0x 30 00 30 00 ... 32 00)`

to

`char * myCharString = "0000000002" (Memory 0x 30 30 ... 32)`

I wrote a function:

```
inline char* newCharFromWchar(wchar_t * utf16String) {
    char * cResult = NULL;
    try {
        std::string szResult = boost::locale::conv::from_utf(utf16String, "UTF-8");
        cResult = new char[szResult.size() + 1];
        memset(reinterpret_cast<void*>(cResult), 0, szResult.size() + 1);
        memcpy(reinterpret_cast<void*>(cResult),
           reinterpret_cast<const void*>(szResult.c_str()),
           szResult.size());
    }
    catch (...) {
        // boost::locale::conv might throw
    }
    return cResult;
}
```

Now the problem is that with `VS2013` it behaves differently to `gcc` and `clang`, i.e.

```
// VS 2013 behaves as expected
wchar_t * utf16String = "0000000002" (Memory 0x 30 00 30 00 ... 32 00)
char * cResult = "0000000002" (Memory 0x 30 30 ... 32)

// both gcc and clang NOT as expected:
wchar_t * utf16String = "0000000002" (Memory 0x 30 00 30 00 ... 32 00)
char * cResult = "2" (Memory 0x 32)
```

Both boost implementation of `gcc` and `clang` seem to use only the last 2 bytes of my input `wchar_t`, though it is parsed correctly regarding the start and end address of the input.

What am I missing?

Comment: `from_utf(utf16String, "UTF-16")`?

Comment: @YSC Nope. Target should be "UTF-8"

Comment: `new` … `memset` … `memcpy` … `reinterpret_cast<void*>` raise *so* many red flags. Reconsider this code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph True story.. Consider it to be the alpha version ;-)

Comment: Actually I think it works for me, using whatever GCC/Boost Coliru is using: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8c3a165a41dc5ec (note that the memory layout is different since `wchar_t` is apparently 4 bytes on this platform).

Comment: @KonradRudolph After adding some testcases I think most likely there has to be something wrong with the input parameters rather than the boost locale which VS2013 kindly ignores.. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

VS2013 takes `wchar_t` as 16-Bit character, while both gcc and clang take it a 32-Bit character (on my machine).

So if I store `0x 30 00 30 00 ... 32 00` as `wchar_t` it only works with VS2013 as expected. `boost::locale` will assume that `0x 30 00 30 00` is a single character instead of two, as I expected. The resulting output therefore is completely different between these platforms.